# How do I create a database using Ruby's DBI?

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, dbi

I'm developing a small Ruby application that I'd like to work with both PostgreSQL and MySQL.

It seems like Ruby/DBI is the most straightforward way to do this; I don't want to install a heavyweight ORM like ActiveRecord or something. Unfortunately, it seems like Ruby/DBI makes it simple to connect if you already have a database but I can't figure out how to connect to a server without a DB and issue the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

So far I have this:

```
dbh = DBI.connect("DBI::Pg", "username", "password")
```

but I get this error when I try and connect: `Invalid Data Source Name`. Any idea of what I can do?

Also, if I can get a 'databaseless handle' I was wondering if there was a DBI method to `select_db` and drop into a database to execute further queries. That's secondary though and I can live without it.

Comment: Having used DBI for the same reasons, and had a lot of trouble with mysql libs and generally needing to write too much code to get things done, I'd suggest using [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), far, far easier and better IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `postgres` database so you could try:

```
dbh = DBI.connect('dbi:Pg:postgres', 'username', 'password')
```

And then execute your `CREATE DATABASE` from there. Also, the first argument to [`connect`](http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/DBI.html#M000004) is supposed to be:

> `dbi:Driver:database_conn_args`

Where `Driver` is the database driver (case sensitive) and `database_conn_args` is usually the database name.